# How can I join two polygons that are within the same layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I have two polygons in QGIS that are within the same layer and I want to merge them so they are not in two different polygons, which means that the gap between them sould not exist. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: You could physically move one polygon to the other by editing the shapefile and using the **Move Feature(s)** tool, then you could select both polygons and use the **Merge Selected Features** tool (from the _Edit_ toolbar).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The trick is that I need the polygon from the left hand side to be exactly where it is located.

Comment: Is there a way to take the convex hull of both shapes with a very high tolerance - ie. snapping almost to each vertex then 'across' the gap?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know Python, try [OpenJump GIS](http://www.openjump.org/). It can do things not present in QGIS

1) the polygons

[image]

2) unions in the same layer

[image]

3) Convex Hull

[image]

3) Concave Hull

[image]

4) you can adjust parameters

[image]

But is is the best result that you will get without programming (how to join the polygons, nodes, vertices ?)

[image]

(one result with [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html))

Answer (score 3):

A quick way to get an acceptable result is the Expand-Shrink method, but for vectors

In this image we have the original shapes.

- Step 1 is to create a dissolved buffer that will join the two features, with the buffer distance (x) being more or less the gap. (black line)
- Step 2 is to create another buffer with a negative (-x) of the aforementioned value (blue line)

The result works well for strait segments, but adds some area to the polygons at corners.
[image]

I'm sure there are additional steps one can take to refine the results.

Answer (score 2):

Try concave hull plugin. It allows you to group features or build clusters before applying a concave hull. It's available from the plugin repo. Examples and some background on its git web page.