# Removing space between multipart polygon in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, editing, multipart

I am looking for an efficient method to edit and remove the space between multipart polygons in QGIS 3. I have an example below which should hopefully be clear:

**Multipart polygon**

[image]

**Final result**

[image]

I know I can trace around the perimeter to create a new feature but this isn't always practical. Ideally I would like to edit it in place without the need of creating a new layer.

Comment: try the minimum bounding geometry tool.

Comment: In case if you have an `"id"`, shared between polygons that must be merged, then you may be interested in this article [Filling gaps between polygons using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293695/filling-gaps-between-polygons-using-qgis/293709). Otherwise, you may check this [How can I join two polygons that are within the same layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173934/how-can-i-join-two-polygons-that-are-within-the-same-layer-in-qgis).

Comment: You can find from old answers some "apply buffer - union - apply negeative buffer" workflows, like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193746/merging-two-adjacent-polygons-which-borders-are-not-touching-each-other

Comment: @user30184, damn I was not lucky to find your link...it is what I was looking for. Probably, only the true author knows how to find his answers.

Comment: @Taras Accepted answer used **OpenJUMP** and this question was tagged with qgis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two adjacent polygons which borders are not touching each other?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193746/merging-two-adjacent-polygons-which-borders-are-not-touching-each-other)

Comment: @csk thanks but the minimum bounding geometry tool does not maintain shape.

Comment: I wanted it all to be in QGIS so the possible duplicate is not ideal.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/327254/120129

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, I think that a good workaround can be afforded by activating snapping options and creates a 'New scratch layer', as in following image, because it is necessary to include 4 critical vertices in a new layer.

[image]

Afterward, you can use merge processing tool (with 'New scratch layer' and original multipolygon) for producing a layer as follows; where I manually edited id attributes table (it can be automatized with a python script) to facilitate last dissolve process.

[image]

Finally, dissolving by id (Dissolve Processing Tool), it can be obtained expected result:

[image]

Comment: May I ask which OS are you working on? Some sort of Linux distribution?

Comment: Yes, GNU/ Debian 10 (code name buster; actual stable version).

Comment: Thanks for your workaround - it is a shame there is not a native tool to do this. The minimum bounding geometry tool is so close but just doesn't maintain the desired shape.

Comment: The key process is doing automatically the 'New scratch layer' for including the 4 critical vertices. Done this it would be possible for all processes with PyQGIS. I will think in it.